# Query MySQL global variables with a SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am able to use the `SHOW` command in MySQL to query the Global Variables. In particular I wanted to query this variable:

`show global status like "Ssl_server_not_after"`

Is there a way to use a `SELECT` statement and get access to those various or statuses? Is it possible even?

Comment: explore ***Information_schema **** is the default MySql database wich contains information of the stored MySql Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Status variables" are not system variables (`SELECT @@GLOBAL.Ssl_server_not_after` produces "Unknown variable" error), they're like properties of server's STATUS object...

```sql
select * 
from performance_schema.global_status 
where variable_name like 'Ssl_server_not%'
```