# MySQL: Query value of (global) variable

Tags: mysql

I know it is possible to print global or session variables using

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
```

or

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES;
```

If I want to investigate a specific variable, I can use something like e.g.

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin_trust_function_creators';
```

which results in something of this form:

```
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF   |
+---------------------------------+-------+
```

This works just fine for manual inspection of the respective values, but in order to programmatically query the values of such variables, I am bothered by two things in this format:

1. It returns two columns: The variable name and its value. However, I am only interested in the value as the name I already know in advannce (after all I specified it in the query)
2. The actual value seems to be a string representation of the actual value. When setting this specific value, I have so far only seen integers `0` and `1` to be used, so I expect that this setting should actually be stored as a numeric type. However, here it is returned as a string (`OFF`). While easy enough to convert this into a boolean value, I am unsure whether this string representation might depend on things like locale, in which case the conversion to bool might end up getting tricky.

So my question is: Is there a way to concisely query only the value of a given (global) variable that returns its value as-is, without attempting to pretty-print/stringify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this thanks to the following answer at [Query MySQL global variables with a SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185047/3907364)

If you know the name of a given global or session variable, you can query for its actual value via

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.<variableName>;
```

or

```
SELECT @@SESSION.<variableName>;
```

respectively.

So for the provided example, we can use

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.log_bin_trust_function_creators;
```

to get

```
+------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.log_bin_trust_function_creators |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        0 |
+------------------------------------------+
```