# Warning in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I don't understand what this exactly means!

```
RuntimeWarning: Accessing the database during app initialization 
is discouraged. To fix this warning, avoid executing queries in AppConfig.ready() or when your app modules are imported.
  warnings.warn(self.APPS_NOT_READY_WARNING_MSG, category=RuntimeWarning)
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

Comment: It means there is code somewhere in your application that accesses the database before it should.  We can't say exactly where, without seeing all of your application code.

Comment: Is that the full error message, or was there a code traceback along with it?

Comment: In addition to John's comment, you can check the docs for this error,
e.g. this one https://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/applications.html
It contains an example of how you can get this error. Maybe that's your case.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have a form or a model that queries the database as part of its definition, which would mean that the database query happens when the module is _imported_, which is too early.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering this warning after upgrading my Django version from 4.2 to 5.0. It seems the warning stems from django-apscheduler in my case, though the cause might vary in your project.

To diagnose the root of this warning, follow these steps:

1. Check the apps.py files in your apps and search for any ORM commands. If you don't find anything follow the next steps.
2. Enable query logging in your database. In my instance, I followed [these instructions for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72074904/mysql-query-value-of-global-variable).
3. Start your project and inspect the logs. Analyzing executed queries could provide insights into the cause of the warning.